# Android - cordova, Extract code from apk

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

i am developing phonegap jquery mobile app. i am build successfully.i am try to extract apk (apk to Zip and extracting zip ) i am getting total code .How to secure to my apk.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390733/protect-contents-of-cordova-android-app

Comment: Please suggest me link how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two points to protect:

1. Java code
2. JavaScript code

## Java code

Usually here nothing to protect. Because usually you will have only one simple `Activity` which will load index.html to `WebView`, and it's all.

Also here maybe plugins java code, but I sure that this isn't your responsibility to protect third-party code

## JavaScript code

Here you can use some JS obfuscation tool or library (just search 'js obfuscator' I sure you will found a lot of them)